# Can there be a circonflex on a "w" in Welsh?

Tags: orthography, diacritics

Consider the page [Wrexham Glyndŵr University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrexham_Glynd%C5%B5r_University). Why is there a circonflex on the *w*? Does this exist in [Welsh spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_language#Orthography)?

Comment: This is a forum about English, not Welsh!

Comment: Welsh is not a dialect of English, either. I suggest this question ought to be closed or removed altogether.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about English.

Comment: The question about whether 'Wrexham Glyndwr University' is acceptable in English articles when referring to what is seen here as 'Wrexham Glyndŵr University' _is_ on-topic, unless it boils down to POB. Nationalism can be tricky, but in England we don't worry too much about our co-fighters against COVID across the Channel calling our capital city _Londres_.

Comment: Also, you are asking about a UNIVERSITY Website. I think it's safe to say they know the rules of their language better than most.

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable for the English name of an institution (especially based in Wales!) to use the "native" form of a person's name. However, asking about that native language *itself* is off-topic here.

Comment: Excuse-me, I did not pay attention to the scope of this StackExchange when asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the circumflex exists in the Welsh spelling:

[Circumflex  In Welsh](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex) :

> The circumflex is known as hirnod "long sign" or acen grom "crooked accent", but more usually and colloquially as to bach "little roof".
>
> ***It lengthens a stressed vowel (a, e, i, o, u, w, y), and is used
>   particularly to differentiate between homographs; e.g. tan and tân,
>   ffon and ffôn, gem and gêm, cyn and cŷn, or gwn and gŵn.***
>
> However the  circumflex is only required on elongated vowels if the same word
>   exists without the circumflex - "nos" (night), for example, has an
>   elongated "o" sound but a circumflex is not required as the same word
>   with a shortened "o" doesn't exist.

the circumflex,

> due to its function as a disambiguating lengthening sign, is used in polysyllabic words with word-final long vowels. The circumflex thus indicates the stressed syllable (which would normally be on the penultimate syllable), since in Welsh, non-stressed vowels may not normally be long.
>
> This happens notably where the singular ends in an a, to, e.g.
>   singular camera, drama, opera, sinema → plural camerâu, dramâu,
>   operâu, sinemâu; however, it also occurs in singular nominal forms,
>   e.g. arwyddocâd; in verbal forms, e.g. deffrônt, cryffânt; etc.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: While the question might just be on-topic (should the circumflex be used when referring to say the university in an English article), your answer deals with the requirements when one is using Welsh.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I think my answer fits what the OP is asking. And that’s fine for me.

Comment: So you'd have been happy about the time a person asked here about the best way to keep a goldfish? Admittedly, they asked the question using the English language. ELU has pretty reasonable regulations: no questions about how to raise  animals, construct face-masks, or use Welsh.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I thought  this was a site about the language/s spoken by natives in the UK.

Comment: @Hachi - this site is about **English** language and usage. English is just one of the languages spoken by natives and immigrants in the UK.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I’ll have to check that in the rules.

Comment: @Hachi Thanks for the information, however.

Comment: Have you checked the rules yet? Those wanting to promote Welsh or Scots Gaelic say might consider setting up dedicated sites, where questions about English would be likewise off-topic.